# Rails 3.2 app with no models, which form validation to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

Currently I'm building Rails application that uses Faraday to get needed info about models from a remote server. So no models. As far as I understand `gem client_side_validation` is of no use in this case.
What I'm asking about - **is there ready to use form validation** ? Of course there's always  self made way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need ActiveModel::Validations to enable validations. Please take a look at the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html) for the module.

According to docs:

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  validates_each :first_name, :last_name do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add attr, 'starts with z.' if value.to_s[0] == z
  end
end
```

you can also use `validates_presence_of :name` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, personally I prever syntax `validates :name, ...` more

Comment: me too. I just wanted to be clear that you get full rails validation syntax.